# Adding space Before and after the Svg:rect - d3.js

Tags: jquery, graph, svg, d3.js, rickshaw

I am appending a Extra svg:rect in to the bar chart when it meets certain condition. It works and the line appears. But It appears right next to the bar. So I need to have some space exactly before and after that extra Rect.

This code is not working. I have added padding-right. Also added the same functionality to the xLine class in a seperate css file. But still it is not working. What should I do here?

Here is the code of the Extra Rect I am appending

```
var xLine = d3.selectAll(svg).append('rect').data(series.stack.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.y !== null
                })).attr({
                    'width' : 0.4,
                    'height' : 400,
                    'fill' : '#09213a',
                    'padding-right' : '40',
                    'x' : function(d) {
                        return graph.x(a = a + brand_Count[j])
                        },
                    'y' : function(d) {
                        return graph.y(1300)
                    },
                    'class' : 'xLine'
                });
```

Comment: add unit px, em, or % and if its not library then use .css({width:..., height:....}) etc instead of attr()

Answer (score 2):

SVG elements are placed absolutely, not automatically laid out with paddings and margins and such. You can either add a `transform` attribute where needed to move the parts that need moving, or you can adjust the rect position and size with the `x, y, width, height` attributes.

`padding-right` has no effect on elements in svg, and isn't even a valid attribute (which could potentially cause issues if svg was extended to have such an attribute, since your content would then change unexpectedly).

Comment: x, y, width, height is not helping to add the space in the axis.. also tried Transform-translate attribute. Same result. there is no other possible way to add a blank space in D3?  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ash: It looks like you want to _push_ the adjacent element to the right? If so, you will need to set a `transform` on the next element. Alternatively, if you want to _pull_ this `rect` to the left (?), then something like `.attr('transform', 'translate(-40,0')` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add the desired padding to the value that the scale returns, e.g.

```
var padding = 5;
// more code...
  'x' : function(d) {
    return graph.x(a = a + brand_Count[j]) + padding
  },
```

Comment: X position shouldn`t change bro!! This method is changing the x position

Comment: You will have to change the position to achieve what you want.